# Mapping a JSON to java classes

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to parse a JSON string with jackson that looks like:

```
{
  "name":"John",
  "Wrapper":{
    "id":0
   }
}
```

I am trying to prevent having to make another Java class for `Wrapper` and simply map it to an integer instead. I tried using [`@XmlElementWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html) even though the documentation states:

> This is primarily intended to be used to produce a wrapper XML element
>   around collections.

But that does not work. I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@44eefb4; line: 1, column: 15] (through reference chain: Test["Wrapper"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseInteger(StdDeserializer.java:305)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:795)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:782)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:579)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2723)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1854)
    at Test.main(Test.java:37)
```

Here is a runnable example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        String json = 
                "{" +
                "\"name\":\"John\","+
                "\"Wrapper\":{"+
                "   \"id\":0}"+
                "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector());
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
        Test test = mapper.readValue(json, Test.class);
        System.out.println(test.toString());
    }

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Wrapper")
    @XmlElement(name="id")
    private Integer wrapperId;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test [name=" + name + ", wrapperId=" + wrapperId + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are interested in JSON-binding providers other than Jackson, here is link that demonstrates how to support your use case using EclipseLink MOXy's `@XmlPath` annotation:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/binding-to-json-xml-geocode-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson provides limited number of structure transform annotations (`@JsonUnwrapped`, root value wrapping), but not something for this use case. I think there is actually a feature request for this particulal use case (it'd be [`@JsonWrapped`](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-781) I think).

For what it is worth, Jackson JAXB annotation module does recognize the annotation, but it is not used for JSON (it is used for XML backend, but just for `Collection` and array valued properties).

I would just add a simple static class `Wrapper`; or, if it is a common idiom, shared generic class `Wrapper<T>`, to use for all kinds of wrapped values. Amount of code would be simple, and Object structure would then match 1-to-1 with JSON data structure.

Comment: I ended up going just creating the class. It was actually the only instance I ran into so far. It just seemed like I should not of had to. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: It depends on one's philosophy regarding data-binding: whether use of transformation functions is preferred over simplicity of one-to-one mapping. Sort of two ways to think about it; and in former, yes, one would resolve this impedance between JSON and model.